# ¿Ejecutar Como Administrador Aplicación en C#?

Tags: c#

Me podrían ayudar a resolver esta duda. Tengo una app que detiene servicios de windows de otra aplicación. El problema surge que necesita ser ejecutada como administrador para que funcione, sino se ejecuta así, sale el error "El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"'.' o  No se puede abrir el servicio (aqui me aparece el nombre del servicio a detener) en el equipo '.'.

Por lo tanto me gustaría saber si via código puedo iniciar mi aplicación en modo administrador y mucho mejor seria si bajo código lleve el usuario y contraseña del administrador, ya que son para unas computadoras que usan el mismo usuario admin y contraseña y por ende que el usuario pueda usar la app sin necesidad de introducir clave o confirmar si es administrador. Todo esto lo deseo hacer en un usuario estándar y no administrador.

Cabe resaltar que he probado este código:

```
var usuario = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var grupos = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(usuario);

grupos.IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

El cual en la solución la ultima linea me tira false pero yo soy administrador. También tengo este código:

```
ProcessStartInfo aplicacionWindows = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
aplicacionWindows.FileName = "Nombre de la app.exe";
aplicacionWindows.Verb = "runas";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = aplicacionWindows;
process.Start();
```

Me abre el mismo programa como administrador, pero debo de hacer todo el proceso de nuevo.

Alguna ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Comment: tienes que agregarle a tu proyecto un app.manifest y en la linea <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" /> cambiar a  <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: Exactamente estoy estudiando esto en google jeje  ,<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> que pasa si este ultimo lo pongo en true?

Comment: no, no tengo idea que hace :)